# Is this just illogical or there's function that can do this?

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

| key | keytype | elements |
| --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | AB | 7 |
| key2 | CD | 3 |
| key2 | CD | 2 |
| key3 | AB | 4 |
| key3 | AB | 3 |
| key3 | AB | 1 |

And I'm using this code:

```
select key,
  count(*) as rcount,
  sum(elements) as ecount
from keyhistory
group by key
order by key
```

The result looks like this:

| key | rcount | ecount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | 1 | 7 |
| key2 | 2 | 5 |
| key3 | 3 | 8 |

The problem is that I also need to show the column `keytype` from the first table on the second table. A key will always have same `keytype` (so all key1 occurrences will be `AB`, all key2 occurrences will be `CD`, and so on). I want to merge the `keytype` rows in a single row respective to their 'key', like I did with `elements` in `ecount`, like the following example:

| key | rcount | ecount | keytype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | 1 | 7 | AB |
| key2 | 2 | 5 | CD |
| key3 | 3 | 8 | AB |

Do SQL have any function or syntax which I can use to reach the result of the last table using the values of the original table?

Comment: What SQL you are using? MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite, ..?
What is the problem when you add `keytype` in the `SELECT`?

Comment: I'm using MySQL with Microsoft SQL Studio. When I add the column `keytype` along the  `key` in the select I got the error "Column 'keyhistory.keytype' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just list the keytype in the select and the group by (in your original query)

```
select key,keytype,
  count(*) as rcount,
  sum(elements) as ecount
from keyhistory
group by key,keytype
order by key
```

Comment: I was using the solution @WardenUnleashed provided and it was working, but I tested your and it is also working and it is even simplier! Apparently I was missing adding `keytype` to the `group by´.

Answer (score 0):

[`INNER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp), an  alias, and `DISTINCT` clause should do it,

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    [KeyStats].*,
    [keyhistory].keytype
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [key],
        count(*) as rcount,
        sum(elements) as ecount
    FROM keyhistory
    GROUP BY [key]
    ORDER BY [key]
) as KeyStats
INNER JOIN keyhistory ON keyhistory.[key] = KeyStats.[key]
```

Comment: Hello @WardenUnleashed! Thanks for the reply! I tested your answer and it adds the `keytype` column alongside the `ecount` and `recount` as I wanted. But for some reason `GROUP BY` apparently don't work, the rows aren't merged and every row has the final sum/count in the `ecount` and `rcount` columns. Any idea? I tried even adding the `GROUP BY` outside the parentheses but it didn't work too.

Comment: You might be able to just do a `SELECT DISTINCT` instead to limit the rows.

Comment: Apparently using `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of the first `SELECT` resolved the issue for now. I don't know how this will affect the later study of the table since I'm just a newbie, but for now it works. Thanks, mate!

Comment: @Robbie if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71534984/4688413) also gets you the desired results I would recommend using it over the one I just provided

Answer (score 0):

[`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) could solve this.

```sql
select key,
  count(*) as rcount,
  sum(elements) as ecount,
  GROUP_CONCAT(keytype)
from keyhistory
group by key
order by key
```

> SQL Server use [`STRING_AGG`](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-string_agg-function/) instead.

> If you have unique value for `keytype`, SQLite default allowing  query directly: `SELECT keytype FROM test GROUP BY key`, but it also allow [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/)

Or instead group it directly:

```sql
select key,
  count(*) as rcount,
  sum(elements) as ecount,
  keytype
from keyhistory
group by key, keytype
order by key
```

Comment: Your answar, as well the answers from @tinazmu  and @WardenUnleashed provided, works like charm. Apparently my biggest mistake was not adding `keytype` to `GROUP BY` thinking only one column name should fit here.